# Who has banned me?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

I have been banned for an unknown reason. I don't know who banned me. Who banned me?

Comment: I love free downvotes!!!!!

Comment: It's likely that you were automatically banned by a computer. Why do you hate our robotic overlords?

Comment: *Bzzz*! You can only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Anna I, for one, welcome our new computer overlords.

Answer (score 0):

Send an email to the 'Contact Us' link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: by  mistake i flagged comment of Rafe Kettler instead of cheetah

Comment: @Lance I'm still a bit confused :(

Comment: @Rafe, Yeh, I have no idea what he was thinking.

Comment: Why would you encourage people to do this for such a well-known case? It's been the subject of innumerable questions here, suggesting to search would have been a better option than emailing the team.

Comment: @Code, his question did not make it clear what his problem was.  For an actual banning, this would be the best course of action.

Comment: @Cody, courtesy notification for the above comment (I've read your profile, but never seen it happen before!)

Comment: For the record, actual bannings are always accompanied by a message. The system does not allow a ban otherwise.